# Efficient way of kron(A,I) (tensor product or Kronecker product) of sparse matrix A and eye I

Tags: python, scipy, tensor

I am implementing exact-diagonalization codes for spin chains. After I get the low-lying eigenstates, I need to average them on various operators. One type of operator is of the following form

```
$$I\otimes I\otimes\cdots\otimes I\otimes S_{a}\otimes I\otimes\cdots\otimes I\otimes S_{b}\otimes I\otimes\cdots\otimes I\otimes I$$
```

or rather in plain text

```
I (X) I (X) ... (X) I (X) Sa (X) I (X) ... (X) I (X) Sb (X) I (X)...(X) I (X) I
```

where `(X)` represents the tensor product / Kronecker product.

It would be nice if I can get a 10x speed up for the computation of 
`kron(A,eye(I.shape[0]**n)) = A (X) I (X) I (X) ... (X) I # I` repeat n times

I came up with simple ideas as reshaping `kron(eye(I.shape[0]**n), A)`, but reshape of sparse matrix is not well implemented (also not efficient) in scipy.

Has anyone done the same thing before?

Comment: Since you are asking for speedup, I assume you have working code.  Show it along with an example we can test.  Otherwise we will just be guessing as to what you've done.

Comment: Up to now I directly use kron( A, eye(2 * * (L)) ) where L is between 15 and 25 and A is a scipy.sparse matrix, usually of dimension (2 * * L) x (2*  * L). I want to speed it up because profiling indicates that the bottleneck is on kron(). The reshape idea is to construct block-diagonal matrix from A, and interchange columns and rows. But for a scipy.sparse matrix, reshape is not efficient. It seems to me that toarray() is also not a good idea ...

Comment: `sparse.kron`?  That works with the `coo` format of both matrices.  `sparse.bmat` also works with `coo` attributes.  But I vaguely recall a previous question along this line, making new matrix with `A's` linedup along the diagonal.

Comment: `sparse.block_diag` uses `bmat`.  Look at those codes to see how they manipulate the attributes of the args to produce a new matrix.  Usually they build the new one using `coo` style attributes.